# Installed bing maps but appears on every page

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

i've added bing maps to my orchard project.
I'm then displaying it from my 'AsideSecond' widget.  My Q being I have added an about page and a blog page.  Why does the bing maps appear on every page? main menu, about, and blog page.

How can I set it to only appear on one page...about page for example

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a widget layer that is shown only on your about page, using the `url(...)` layer rule syntax. You can then assign your widget to the `AsideSecond` zone on that layer.

See [Adding a Layer](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Managing-widgets#AddingaLayer).